# Android - Intent declaration crashing my app on boot

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, boot

I have an app with :

- an activity class that allows the user to set multiple alarms.
- a service class to manage those alarms in the background.
- a receiver class to do certain work when the alarm is called.

Everything works fine.

Now I want to automatically start the service when the phone boots up. The onBootReceiver is received but the app crashes (NPE) when this line is reached in my service class:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.getContext(),AReceiver.class);
```

I can't use **this** instead of MainActivity.getContext() either.

Any ideas of what may be causing this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code sample, it looks like the MainActivity class is not being initialized when being passed into the Intent. This means that the getContext() method will return a null value, and thats where your error is.

You need to use getContext() or getApplicationContext() from a initialized object. If this proves impossible, you could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android).

Comment: Thanks Mark D, it works now.
I had to use Rohit Ghatol's method available in your link.
Thanks again, I really appreciate it :)